# Google App Engine - hash password on server

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, hash

I have recently started to learn about google app engine. I have encountered a problem. How do hash a password on google app engine? Im planning to pass password to the datastore. There I will hash the password and store the hash? Any tips or thoughts?

thx all!

Comment: You might consider using AppEngine's built-in user authentication code (though that does mean users have to have a Google account) - it saves having to re-implement such logic.

Comment: Is it possible do some java service side? I want to create a customize login on android app

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking at implementing your own custom login, you can definitely use popular hashing algorithms for the same. You can use the `MessageDigest` classes for teh same. Alternately, 3rd party libraries also exist, which you could use. E.g. [Jasypt library](http://www.jasypt.org/easy-usage.html)

Comment: the problem is how to use the library/class on google app engine. i found some info here https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm and i have tried the class in eclipse. however im planning to hash the password on google app engine but i dont know how

Comment: @johncena the link in the answer by Nick has an example which works using the `java.security.MessageDigest` class referenced in this answer, with `SHA-256`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure what you're doing, you're best of relying on a library. Having said that, there are great code samples for password management on the owasp site.

For example, [here is a page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Hashing_Java) with code samples on how to manage this correctly and a good explanation of all the element requires. You'll need to adapt the code for storage on appengine, or just use CloudSQL